# How to replace a part of a link using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

/de/test/test2-example/base/FROM/NOW/ON/IT/DOES/NOT/MATTER

I have only to replace the part /de/test/test2-example/base/ with another part: /de/product/prod-new/base/ Which rewrite rule do I have to use?

after base/ there are several links so it has to be permanent for all cases.

Comment: You are close, try this: `RewriteRule ^/de/groeden/infos-service/adressen/base/(.*) /de/adressen-groeden/detail/base/$1 [L,NC]`.  You are missing the starting `/` and `(.)` will match only 1 character.  The 404 error you get, look in the address bar what it tried to access to debug.

Comment: Does not redirect me to target URL...Still 404 the adressbar get not changed

Comment: If the address bar does not change, do you have `RewriteEngine On` in your configuration?  Is the rewrite module loaded? Then in your browser, start the developer tools (ex F12 on Chrome) and see if the server returns you a redirect header or not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

RewriteRule ^de/test/test2-example/base/(.*)$ /de/product/prod-new/base/$1 [R=301,L]